# Prolog : toplevel: Undefined procedure (simple tree)

Tags: prolog

*Hello , i have a simple Homework in Prolog and i am getting this error :*

**ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: root/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)**

[The Tree Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upJyT.png)

code in file :

```
 node(3).
 node(1).
 node(2).
 node(6).
 node(5).
 edge(3,1).
 edge(1,2).
 edge(3,6).
 edge(6,5). 
 root(X ):- node( X ),not edge(X , _).
 leaf(X):- node(X) ,not edge(X, _ ).
 internal_node( X ):- edge( X , _ ),  edge( _ , X ).
```

i am getting the error when :
  root(3).
  leaf(5).
but not when:
  internal_node(1).

Thank you,

Comment: Sure you did not get an error message like `Syntax error: Operator expected` for using `not`? Replace it by `\+` twice.

Comment: no syntax error , i replaced it :    root(X ):- node( X ),\+ edge(X , _).  same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a logic mistake in the first declaration , try this it should work :

```
 root(X ):- node( X ),\+ edge(_ , X).
      leaf(X):- node(X) ,\+ edge(X, _ ).
      internal_node( X ):- edge( X , _ ),  edge( _ , X ).
```

Comment: @false yes just checked it again , still gives me an error but with Z,Kal code it works, anyway thank you for help